# Java best solution for repeated task in Runnable

Tags: java, swing, jframe, eclipse-neon

What would you recommend me to achieve my goal? 
I want to repeat `Robot` stuff (keys pressed) in a regular intervall. Description is also in my code.
I´m using `eclipse neon with windowbuilder`(java/swing/jframe).

```
package patrick;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;

import javax.management.timer.Timer;

public class Background implements Runnable {

    public boolean isRunning = true;
    int intervall = 0;
    Robot r = null;


    public Background(int i)
    {
        this.intervall = i;
    }




    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " gestartet!");
        System.out.println("Intervall i: " + intervall);
        try {
            r = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(isRunning)
        {
            //int intervall is given me from my MainWindow Class and represents the minutes (for example I get a 5 which means 5 minutes)
            //now I want to do Robot stuff here that repeats in the given intervall time
        }
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        isRunning = false;
        System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " gestoppt!");
    }

}
```

EDIT:

Background is started from MainWindow Class like this:

```
bg = new Background(itmp);
        th1 = new Thread(bg);
        th1.start();
```

EDIT2: to first Answer

Like this?

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
while(isRunning)
        {
            //int intervall is given me from my MainWindow Class and represents the minutes (for example I get a 5 which means 5 minutes)
            //now I want to do Robot stuff here that repeats in the given intervall time
        }
, delay, period);
```

EDIT3:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(isRunning)
                {
                    //int intervall is given me from my MainWindow Class and represents the minutes (for example I get a 5 which means 5 minutes)
                    //now I want to do Robot stuff here that repeats in the given intervall time
                }
            }
        }, 0, intervall*6000);
```

Comment: Might be worth your while looking into a timer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Do you mean like I did in edit2?

Comment: you would need to make a TimerTask object, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: I´ve added code in edit3. You mean like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) probably suits your needs pretty well. using for example `public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)`, you'd be able to set a timer that executes a task after a number of milliseconds. So in your case 300000 milliseconds (5 minutes) and a [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

```
long delay = 300000L;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }
}, delay);
```

Comment: Like my edit 3?

Comment: @Patrick260284, yes.

Comment: Note, if the stuff you want do execute updates GUI components then you should be using a Swing Timer, not an AWT Timer. All updates to Swing components should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread. The Swing Timer automatically executes on the EDT.

Comment: What do mean by "updates GUI components"? Like for example when I want to set the text of a label? The only GUI comps that are "affected" are two buttons. One starts the thread, the other stops it.

Comment: camickr means that for example if you have a label where which its value will be updated from these tasks/timers ,you should use swing timers instead of awt timers